# Run upload and delete file on inotifywait notification

Tags: json, bash, curl

I have a looping script that uploads a file to a server and upon completion returns a JSON object to the terminal on success with assorted information about the file/upload.

Is there a way I can have a 2nd script running that watches for the confirmation of this upload so I can delete the file locally?

EDIT: For context this is the looping script:

```
#monitor directory for new files
inotifywait -m -q -r -e MOVED_TO --format '%f' /var/www/html/uploads/ | while read FILE
do
#when new file detected, upload to website
curl -u <user:pass> -T /var/www/html/uploads/$FILE https://www.website.com
done
```

Response on successful upload:

```
{
"meta": {
    "code": 200
},
"results": {
    "id": 122,
    "sha1sum": "3fcdbdb04baa29ce695ff36af81eaac496364e82",
    "status": "B"
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the looping script?

Comment: FYI, all-caps names are reserved -- you shouldn't use them for your own variables. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: (As an aside, kibitzing on the question title -- it's not output "to the terminal" if you're redirecting stdout into your while loop; it's just plain vanilla program output on stdout; direct output to the terminal would be something written to /dev/tty, which is harder to intercept/redirect. Alternately, the title could read as wanting to filter through / intercept all content literally written to the console during an interactive session, which is also a very different question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  curl \
    --fail \
    -u "$user:$pass" \
    -T "/var/www/html/uploads/$file" \
    https://www.website.com \
    && rm -f "/var/www/html/uploads/$file"
done < <(inotifywait -m -q -r -e MOVED_TO --format '%f' /var/www/html/uploads/)
```

Key points:

- Use `curl --fail` to return a successful exit status only if the upload was accepted by the remote server; so long as the exit status is given in the HTTP header, as opposed to only in the `meta` section, there's no need to parse the JSON response.
- Use `&&` to run the `rm` command only if `curl` exited with a successful status.
- Quote your expansions: `$file` should always be in double quotes, **especially** on the `curl` command line, or else a user can run arbitrary curl commands on your server by putting whitespace inside filenames.
- This is still a little broken, because your `inotifywait` format uses newline delimiters, but newlines are valid inside filenames. Unfortunately, this is hard to avoid due to a design flaw in inotifywait, which doesn't allow NUL delimiters. Other StackOverflow questions exist on this subject, if you want a workaround to be secure against uploaded filenames with literal newlines. See [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/coding/comments/2b7npr/how_to_use_inotifytools_to_trigger_scripts_on/) for an example of an attack using a spoofed filename.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. Still a bit new to this, so thanks for pointing out the flaws and explaining the key points. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can. Just use a pipe or &&. For example

Remove the upload.sh when it's done while saving the output of upload.sh to a log file

```
./upload.sh >> uploadlog.txt && rm upload.sh
```

Pipe the output of upload.sh to another shell script that handles the output of upload.sh and removes the upload.sh file

```
./upload.sh | ./uploadhandler.sh
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the _script_ that should be deleted? I read it as the _file_ returned by `inotifywait`, named in the variable FILE.

Comment: Also, `upload.sh` needs to be modified a bit from what the OP gave if it's not to delete things after failed uploads.

Comment: When OP posted at the time he didn't give any examples so this was the best solution I gave with the information he provided.